# Obtener latitud y longitud por separado con leaflet

Tags: leaflet

¿Cómo puedo conseguir los valores de latitud y longitud por separado? estoy usando:

```
function onMapClick(click){
 alert("Youclicked the map at " click.latlng);
}
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve el alert:

> You clicked the map at LatLng(49.815933, 21.595358)

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora? Te ha dado algún error? mira [tour] para conocer el sitio y [ask] para ver cómo realizar las preguntas y que no te las puntúen negativo ni te la eliminen. Pista, ¿has mirado los métodos que tiene click.latlng?

Comment: Perdon, estaba algo incompleta la pregunta. he añadido lo que me aparece en la salida del alert. No me da ningun error, solo que me devuelve LatLng(49.815933, 21.595358) pero lo que necesit es obtener los dos valores por separado. Usando typeOf he podido comprobar que el resultado es de tipo objeto

Comment: Te devuelve Object porque es un objeto, el cual tiene métodos. Si haces .lat te devolverá la latitud y si haces .lng te devuelve la longitud. Ahora no se si hay que poner o no paréntesis.

Comment: De lujo Pablo, me has salvado

Answer (score 0):

pasa eso se utiliza la funcion **split(',')**

La función split de jQuery sirve para dividir una cadena de texto en varias partes según el delimitador que le indiquemos.

```js
 var LatLng= "49.815933, 21.595358";
var lati_long=LatLng.split(",");
//var Longitud 
alert(lati_long[0]);
//var latitud
alert(lati_long[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas operaciones que se pueden hacer con la libreria de Leaflet, sin necesidad de usar otras, en su [documentación](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html) encontrarás más información.
Siguiendo tu código, esto es una opción de conseguir las coordenadas por separado.

```
    map.on('click', onMapClick);

    function onMapClick(click){
        var coordenada = click.latlng;
        var latitud = coordenada.lat; // lat  es una propiedad de latlng
        var longitud = coordenada.lng; // lng también es una propiedad de latlng
        alert("Acabas de hacer clic en: \n latitud: " + latitud + "\n longitud: " + longitud);
    };
```